# Going back to the beginning of the function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the simple code you see below in Jquery, but when the process is finished, I want the function to come back to the front of it and the code to run again when I click it again. How can I do that.
Is there such a thing as the goto method used in the C programming language?

```
$(".ccs .fa-chevron-down").click(function(){
            $(".gorunmez").css("visibility", "visible");
            $(".ccs").css("transform", "translate(0%, -80%)");
            $(this).css("transform", "rotate(180deg)").css("transition", "0.3s");
            $(this).click(function(){
                $(".ccs").css("transform", "translate(0%,-50%)");
                $(this).css("transform","rotate(0deg)").css("transition", "0.3s");
                $(".gorunmez").css("visibility", "hidden");
            });
        });
```

Comment: You don't need such functionality, the function runs automatically from the start when you click the element. Notice, that you're adding a new click listener to the clicked element every time you click on it.

Comment: Name your function. Call it something like `function clickHandler { ...}`. Then you can call it on click `$(".ccs .fa-chevron-down").click(clickHandler)` or whenever you want with `clickHandler();`.